# DES、AES、RC4, which encryption method should I use for cellphone Encode and Decode?

Tags: c#, security

I have an asp.net web app storing user's cellphone number in Sql Server 2005.

I want to use C# to encode cellphone number for security reason.

Which encryption method should I use for cellphone Encode and Decode?

DES、AES、RC4 or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend AES since its newer, but in reality any would work. Unless your afraid of the NSA

A big DB password would also help

Answer (score 0):

use the which has less computational overhead and consuming less battery and secure (not compromised yet)